# How to pass a multivalued field to a custom function

Tags: solr, lucene, multivalue

I’ve been reading answers around this problem but I wanted to make sure that there is another way out of my problem. The thing is that the solution shouldn’t be on index-time, involve indexing a new field or changing this multi-valued field to a single-valued one.

**Problem:**
I need to run a custom function with some fields but I see that it’s not possible to get the value (first value in this case) of a multivalued field. “title”, in my case, is a multi-valued field.

When I try a Solr function:

```
if(exists(title),strdist(title, “string1"),0).
```

This throws the *“can’t use FieldCache on a multivalued field”* error. The same happen when I run a custom function. I can't access a multi-valued field.

**Solutions that doesn’t work for me:**

- Keep a copy of the value into a non-multi-valued field, using an update processor:  This involves indexing a new field.
- Change the field to multiValued=false: This involves using a single-valued field. I will be indexing new data in the future and I need some fields to be multi-valued but I also need to work with them.

Thanks in advance, I spent a lot of time with this without a solution. I’m using Solr 4.10.

*Note:*
I know how to parse a multivalue field but the thing is that Solr doesn't even access to my function, it throws the previous error (looks like it does this on his source function *checkFieldCacheSource*)